# Zend Framework multiple checkbox

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox

I have a multiple check box in zend framework where I have to diaplay image in place of label.

For example:

```
<label for="elId-1222">
 <input type="checkbox" name="elId[]" id="elId-1222" value="1222" checked="checked" class="inputtext">
 <image src="images/yes.png">
</label><br />
```

So in multioptions I have prepared an array of key and value pair, but how will I be able to add an image in place of value so that above image get displayed in label.
My code is as shown below:

```
$multiCheckbox = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox( 'elId', array ( 'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' =>true ) );

$multiCheckbox ->setName( 'elId' )
               ->setLabel('elId')
               ->setRequired( false )
               ->setAttrib('class', 'inputtext')
               ->setDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) )
               ->setMultiOptions( $options );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Decorator ViewScript

For example, this is my case:

```
$fanpages = $this->addElement('MultiCheckbox', 'fanpages', array(
            'label' => 'Fanpages',
            'id' => 'fanpages',
                ));

        //Don't check where value come from
        $this->getElement('fanpages')->setMultiOptions(array())
                ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);

        $this->getElement('fanpages')->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array(
                    'viewScript' => 'loadMyFanpages.phtml',
                    'class' => 'form_element'
            ))));
```

views/script/loadMyFanpage.phtml

```
            <ul class="jp_listfan">
                <?php foreach ($this->element->getMultiOptions() as $option => $value): ?>
                    <li>
                        <input name="fanpages[]" value="<?php echo trim($option); ?>" type="checkbox"/><img src="your/url/images.jpg"/><?php echo trim($value); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

You can print all element with custom HTML based on your need ^_^ hope this help.